# Redirecting multiple senders outgoing mail to multiple recipients with Exim Router

Tags: redirect, exim

I currently have this config and it works as intended

redirect2email_router:

```
driver = redirect
allow_fail
allow_defer
senders = lsearch;/usr/local/atmail/mailserver/senders.txt
data = recipient@domain.com
unseen
```

The problem is when I try to send to multiple recipients instead of one. I tried different syntaxes and even try to use `lsearch` with no luck. Most info out there is pertinent to alias so I'm kind of stuck here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you want to have a number of bcc-recipients each auditing his own subset of senders?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the problem, so here are some variants:

1. You want to send a BCC to the different recipients depend on sender.

You have to create the file `bcc.list` with lines "sender : recipient [: recipient ...]"

```
sender-a@domain.tld : recipient1@domain.tld
sender-a@domain.tld : recipient2@domain.tld
sender-b@domain.tld : recipient2@domain.tld : recipient3@domain.tld
sender-c@domain.tld : recipient1@domain.tld
. . . . .
```

If more then one line defined for specific sender, first one will be always used. Then you have to modify your router:

```
driver = redirect
allow_fail
allow_defer
data = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/path/bcc.list}}
unseen
```

2. Number of BCC for number of recipients should be sended when specific sender is detected

You have to create `bcc.list` with one sender per line:

```
sender-a@domain.tld
sender-b@domain.tld
sender-c@domain.tld
. . . . .
```

And here is the router:

```
driver = redirect
allow_fail
allow_defer
senders = ${lookup{$sender_address}lsearch{/path/bcc.list}{yes}{no}}
data = recipient-1@domain.com : recipient-2@domain.com : recipient-3@domain.com
unseen
```